# How to cache image with as3?

Tags: xml, flash, caching, urlrequest

This is my first post here in StackOverFlow, and I bring you a problem that is hauting my development team.

We are in a project, using stand alone FlashPlayer as a news displayer.
The news feed is a dynamic XML returned from a ASP.Net request and runs on Windows XP.

The problem is:
- The display is running in a bus screen and sometimes the internet connection fails, but we still need to keep displaying images from the news already downloaded. When we manually put a string on a URLRequest it works. The image is downloaded from the server, cached by the IE8, and re-loaded from cache if the internet is gone. But, when we dynamic retrieve the image url from  de XML and puts inside de the URLRequest method, the re-load from cache do not work.

#### eg. 1 - Static string working

```
var pictureUrl:String = "http://www.server-domain/image.jpg"
public var loader:Loader;
loader.load(pictureUrl);
```

RESULT: load image, display, save in cache, re-load from cache if internet connection fails.

#### eg. 2 - Dynamic string NOT working

```
var pictureXmlList:XMLList = xml.item.image as XMLList;
var pictureUrl:String = pictureXmlList[0] as String;
public var loader:Loader;
loader.load(pictureUrl);
```

RESULT: load image, display, save in cache, DO NOT re-load from cache if internet connection fails.

```
IOError: [IOErrorEventType="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2036"]
```

Comment: Are different caching directive headers being sent for the static-string picture and the dynamic picture? You can check this using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: are you sure the problem isn't that you're downloading the xml again over a broken connection? (just a thought)

Comment: Hi Cameron! The ultimate thanks to you!!!

Comment: We've made some tests over the http request using Fiddler and find out the address that was passed to us, were redirecting us to another domain using HTTP redirection (HTTP code 301). Thats was the cause flash was not find the image in browsers cache. Once more, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is making use of Flash's cache (called "Local Shared Objects") instead of relying on the browser's cache -

http://www.bestflashanimationsite.com/tutorials/4/

You can find some advice there. That way it doesn't have to pull in an XML file to get the URL - you'll have it in memory.

I'm not sure if that'll help you or not, but it should at least broaden your options! :)

Comment: Hi Myk, thanks for your answer. We cannot use it, because of logistic. We have 150 buses driving on with displays/cpus installed on them, and we would have to change the web storage settings manually in each one of them.